# Changing generated column to not-generated in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, generated

I've created a MySQL table that contains a generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
    `metadata` JSON NOT NULL,
    `aggregate_version` INT(11) UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS (metadata->'$._aggregate_version') STORED NOT NULL
);
```

How do I change `aggregate_version` to be a non-generated column? The column type should stay the same.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [13.1.8.3 ALTER TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)
>
> ...
>
> - Stored but not virtual generated columns can be altered to nongenerated columns. The stored generated values become the values of the nongenerated column.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `messages`
MODIFY `aggregate_version` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jr6RCEPmJDaER33j9wvVes/0).